# ImageButton with JPEG source causes InflateException

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have 15 `imageButtons` which their src attribute are set as a `JPEG` picture:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"
        android:src="@drawable/agri_b" />
```

When I run my application I get `InflateException` error. I tried to change my `Activity` class to `FragmentActivity` class but nothing changed. I guess something is wrong with my `JPEG` picture size. However my largest picture has 217 KB size. 
Here is the error I get:

```
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713): Process: com.example.TraceYourExpense, PID: 30713
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.TraceYourExpense/com.example.TraceYourExpense.NewBank}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #263: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #263: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at com.example.TraceYourExpense.NewBank.onCreate(NewBank.java:51)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    ... 11 more
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    ... 26 more
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3454)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:88)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
10-18 12:27:32.538: E/AndroidRuntime(30713):    ... 29 more
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT-1**

To check if the error is related to picture size, I removed all the picture sources from `ImageButtons` but unexpectedly I get the error again!! Seriously where is the problem guys?

Comment: its the problem with your image size...try to reduce the size and then use..n firstly try with 2-3 iews..

Comment: @MeenalSharma I removed all the Images source from imageButtons to check if this error is related to my picture size, but even there are no JPEG images I get the error again !! Now I am totally confused

Comment: if possible give full source code so that it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

(if your images are displayed horizontally inside its parent view) 
or

```
 android:layout_height="0dp"
```

(if they're displayed vertically inside its parent). If you're using `layout_weight`, either the width or height of the image should always be 0dp.

Comment: btw fill_parent and match-parent are the same thing, but you should use match_parent since fill_parent has been deprecated ages ago ;)

Comment: That's not the problem, I changed it but I still get the exception

Comment: Then as Aditya Vyas mentioned above, please paste your activity source to help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

may be it is the issue with your code

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

try with this code..if this works..then issue may be..you are setting drawable on both background as well as src..thats why you are getting error..